# configuring https endpoint with WCF self hosting

Tags: wcf, https, endpoint

I have created basichttpendpoint with security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" for my self hosted WCF service.

My server config has:

```
enter code here

   <system.serviceModel>    
       <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IViewerManager" maxBufferSize="655360000"                  maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
    </security>

           </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior" name="Lumedx.ApolloLXPACS.ViewerServiceLibrary.ViewerManager">

    <endpoint name="basicHTTP" address="https://localhost:5100/ViewerService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IViewerManager" contract="Lumedx.ApolloLXPACS.ServiceContracts.IViewerManager"/>
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="https://localhost:5100/ViewerService"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HttpsBehavior">
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>

                <behavior name="SecureBehavior">

                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="RootCATest"
                                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                            storeName="My"
                                            x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>

            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
my windows client config has:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="priorityEndpoint1" value="basicHttpEndpoint"/>

        <add key="maxCommunicationRetries" value="0"/>
    </appSettings>


    <system.serviceModel>


        <bindings>

            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IViewerManager" maxBufferSize="655360000" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>
            <endpoint name="basicHttpEndpoint" address="https://10.10.10.100:5100/ViewerService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IViewerManager" contract="Lumedx.ApolloLXPACS.ServiceContracts.IViewerManager" behaviorConfiguration="HttpsBehavior"/>
        </client>

        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HttpsBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate findValue="RootCATest"
                                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                            storeName="My"
                                            x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
<
```

I have installed and configured certificate.

I am connecting my windows client with the self hosted WCF service with https end points. I captured network traffic using wireshark. All I see in the network traffic is TCP packets between the server and client. When I follow the TCP stream the message does not seem to be encrypted.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Assuming your client and server are on same machine and wireshark has the option to decrypt the encrypted message being passed over hte channel it is doing so. If you are for sure accessing the service on https then it should encrypt the request.

Answer (score 0):

Security mode `TransportWithMessageCredential` encrypts transport (SSL) and leaves message body not encrypted.

Encryption is made using your certificate.

If you see not encrypted data one of the following scenarios happend:

1. Traffic for some reason is not encrypted with ssl
2. Wireshark has access to your certificate and encrypted traffic using it.

Is this looks similar to what you did? http://trycatch.be/blogs/decaluwet/archive/2009/04/08/decrypting-ssl-traffic-using-wireshark.aspx

In any case you should be safe if transport level encryption is enable and your certificate is not compromised.